# Как реализовать инициализацию при декларации собственной коллекции C#

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции, generics

Есть ли возможность инициализации собственной коллекции при её декларации, как во встроенном `List<T>`, то есть так:

```cs
MyCollection<int> mcl = new MyCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для того, чтобы с вашей коллекцией работал синтаксис инициализации, должны быть выполнены следующие условия: класс-коллекция должен реализовывать интерфейс `IEnumerable` (или `IEnumerable<T>`, который наследован от `IEnumerable`), и определять доступный метод `Add` (он может, кстати, быть и методом расширения), который и будет вызван для каждого элемента в списке инициализации.

Код `MyCollection mcl = new MyCollection() {1,2,3,4};` будет скомпилирован в такое:

```
MyCollection tmp = new MyCollection(); // реальное имя будет недоступно
tmp.Add(1);
tmp.Add(2);
tmp.Add(3);
tmp.Add(4);
MyCollection mcl = tmp;
```

[Пруфы](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQGED2ANoQKYDGALgJb4B2AzgNzLKzoCyAngcedXehCY4AZmQBvZOmmYR6AJIBRWgFcAtiQBOAQwr5N6AOIkKy9Vt36AFAEp0AXgB86CgAtN+AO7paJbwDl8Cnk1AAdSDVoKEmBFAA8yElD+WltmJBl0KiitWm1CTAAWdABBYGArbIofOydhAE4rWht0gF8WFBhhAHYJKRksADYijm1s237pSQzMmS4eUkoaWnQ1MgL7Hz8ObiJFlNt0cXQ4ABp0GHORc+LW9Mz2pEegA==)

Интерфейс `IEnumerable` использован не будет, нужен лишь чтобы случайно доступный метод `Add` не приводил к доступности синтаксиса инициализации, имеющего смысл лишь для коллекций.

---

Зачем нужно использование временной переменной? Дело в том, что код списка инициализации вполне может использовать прямо или косвенно `mcl` (например, для случая, если `mcl` — это поле класса или ранее объявленная переменная), и понятно, что код не должен иметь доступа к недоконструированной правой части присвоения.